# How to adjust `binwidth` in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

This may sound a like a repeat question, but hopefully it is not.  In the basic `R graphics` histogram function, we have a option `breaks="FD"`, which gives a reasonable sized binsize for the histogram, do we have any similar simple option for `ggplot2`?  Or even better can we use the same option in `ggplot2`?

I do understand that you can adjust the `binwidth` in `geom_histogram`, but i am looking for a more simpler way to generate aesthetically pleasing and resonable `binsize`.

Comment: Could you calculate it yourself using `nclass.FD` and then set `binwidth` accordingly...?

Comment: I don't believe FD does give a reasonable sized binwidth in many cases (it's generally too large for big datasets) which is one of the reasons it's not built in.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x,breaks="FD")

library(ggplot2)
breaks <- pretty(range(x), n = nclass.FD(x), min.n = 1)
bwidth <- breaks[2]-breaks[1]
df <- data.frame(x)
ggplot(df,aes(x))+geom_histogram(binwidth=bwidth,fill="white",colour="black")
```